# ContentEditable doesn't allow to send php strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with contenteditable .

Before i used textarea for sending posts for text. I want to change it now to use contenteditable.

So contenteditable doesn't allow to send php strings from data. For example

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/ygtLqsea/3/)

In this demo i will show you my html and ajax codes. That is working perfectly, if user send normal text. But if user want to share php codes from his friends like (`<?php echo 'Hi There.';?>`) then problem will be come here. If user write normal text like (`Hi There.`) then not have any problem.

Normaly we are using **val();** if we use textarea like this

`var updateText = $('#post-text-area').`**val()**`;`

I think problem will be come here but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) .it will prevent the tag's passing from html to php .And retrieve the data from php use with [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function() {


      $("body").on("click", ".sendPost", function() {
        var updateText = $('#post-text-area').html();
        var dataString = 'update=' +  encodeURIComponent(updateText);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/posttext.php',
          data: dataString,
          beforeSend: function() {},
          success: function(html) {
           decodeURIComponent(html);
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: so it is sending php code now but why i see the code like this `&lt;?php echo $ssss;?&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`

Comment: its encoding the string to another format .see the [article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) its show formats of encoding

Comment: I understood and solved it. Thanks for your answer. You saved me.